# Click or Touchscreen on JetBoy Sample App

Tags: android, click, keypress, touchscreen

Is there any way I can set this app so instead of taking a keypress, it takes a touch/click event instead?  The other buttons etc in the game handle touchscreen this way, so all it would need to do would be to substitute the "keypress" event with the touch/click one (as there is only one control)

This is the current keypress code I think (sorry if it's wrong - very new to android development!)

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent msg) {
      if (keyCode == 4)
            super.onKeyDown(keyCode, msg);
return mJetBoyThread.doKeyDown(keyCode, msg);
}
```

Thanks!! :)